# how to run main function contain argparse function in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[how to run main function contain argparse function in jupyter notebook? example of main function][1]

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-pretrained_model", default='bert', type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-mode", default='', type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-select_mode", default='greedy', type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-map_path", default='../../data/')
    parser.add_argument("-raw_path", default='../../line_data')
    parser.add_argument("-save_path", default='../../data/')
    parser.add_argument('-n_cpus', default=2, type=int)


    args = parser.parse_args()
    init_logger(args.log_file)
    eval('data_builder.'+args.mode + '(args)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `args = parser.parse_args(args=[])` instead of `args = parser.parse_args()`

Hope this helps.